# how can i pass my password value into other class of my package

Tags: android

Here i want to send the value of "ourpassword" to say in myclass.java so how can i do this??

```
public class SetPassword extends Activity{  
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.set_password);

    final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.setpass);
    Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String  ourpassword=ed.getText().toString();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not an Android problem, you don't need to post your code.Learn first how to code Object Oriented program

Comment: use intents to pass data between activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data between activities use intents.

```
   Intent i= new Intent("com.example.myclass");
   i.puExtra("mypassword",ourpassword);
   startActivtiy(i);
```

In myclass

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (extras != null) {
 String password = extras.getString("mypassword");
}
```

You can also pass value to another class by passing value to the constructor of the class

```
   myClass mc= new myClass(ourPassword);
   mc.doSomething(); //call some method in another class
```

In your myclass

```
   class myClass{
       String pwd;
        public myclass(String password)
        {
               pwd =password;

        } 
        publidc void doSomething()
        {

        }
    }
```

Say you want pass value to a class like asynctask

```
 //pass value as a parameter to the class constructor
MyAsyncTask my= new MyAycTask(ourpassword).execute();
```

In My AsyncTask

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
       public M(String password)//receive value here
       {

       }
    other methods....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create object of this class and get the value as

Define string as static
Object.String;
```

You can also use Use database. thats better way to store and retrieve passwords

Comment: @Razin: Just google it out you will find an immense number of tutorials for using database. If you want to pass data to some other activity you can use intents. But the thing is you should read out the documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

If myclass.java is another Activity class, you can just set the password as a parameter in the intent. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),myclass.class);
intent.putExtra("password", ourpassword);
startActivity(intent);
```

... and then you can get the value from within the myclass.java in the onCreate() method like this:

```
String password = "";
if (getIntent().getStringExtra("password") != null) password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
```

**EDIT**: You place the Intent code in the onClick() method of the submit button.